# Modal Semantic UI React got conflict with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I made a project .net core MVC. I am **using semantic-ui-react modal** and importing its library and link css to work on it, but the problem is the bootstrap css made a conflict with my other CDN semantic-ui-css.

What I meant by that, I open the modal and its is swapping every seconds into the div: **ui modal transitive visible to ui scrolling** ...

I made some tests to see that is **bootstrap is not friend with semantic-ui-css**
because **I remove the link css and it works** but I cannot keep the bootstrap style for my header nav-bar.

Someone knows how to deal with that ? Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to install the css and then import it :
https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage

Comment: Hi dear, I solved my problem yesterday with a simpe editing css file inside the project ! Thanks to your fast answer

Comment: I have tried but got the same issue. The Modal is rendering with 100%